# "Цыплят по осени считают..."

Tags: нормы-языка

Интересно, почему "по осени" и "по весне" сказать можно, а "по зиме" и "по лету" - нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

> Интересно, почему "по осени" и "по весне" сказать можно, а "по зиме" и "по лету" - нельзя?

Можно. По зиме, по весне, по осени - одинаково употребительны, если, конечно, не замыкаться на пословицу.  Аналогично "по утру", "по жаре" и проч. 
"По лету" действительно почти не употребляется, возможно по причине того, что значение лето - "время года" вторично. Но вот "по летнему времени" некогда значило именно "по лету", а совсем не то, что сейчас.
Несколько другое значение имеют пополудни и пополуночи, но в принципе исходный смысл тот же.

> не могу объяснить иностранцу, почему у нас можно сказать "по осени" и "по весне", а "по зиме" и "по лету" - нельзя

Можно. И "по зиме" и даже "по лету". А иностранцу проще сказать, что такие формы малоупотребительны, поскольку обычно соотносятся со сменой основных сезонов года. 
По весне - пахать надо и сеять, по осени - урожай собирать, по зиме - это начало зимы, когда дороги встали. А летом такого ключевого момента нету, разве что косить в начале лета.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы имеете в виду только данную пословицу, то она звучит лишь в форме "по осени", а не "по весне"

Comment: Нет, меня интересует вообще такая норма языка.Я просто столкнулась с тем, что не могу объяснить иностранцу, почему у нас можно сказать "по осени" и "по весне", а "по зиме" и "по лету" - нельзя. Он этого не мог понять.

Answer (score 0):

"По зиме" еще довольно часто употребляется, как и "по осени" и "по весне". "По лету" слышать не приходилось. Видимо, устаревшая форма.

Answer (score 0):

Цыплят по осени считают:Указание на то, что не стоит спешить радоваться раннему успеху, надо его ещё сохранить и развить.
Говорить «Цыплят по зиме, по весне, по лету считают» вообще не стоит. Ведь наше выражение имеет определённое значение: если цыпленок дожил до осени, то он окреп; значит,  ему ничего не угрожает и на лето он будет курицей или петухом.